# select multiple column for calender in oracle application express

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to display multiple column data from database in one column in calender oracle application express

my SQL query is like this

```
SELECT EXPDATE, 'Exp: ' || SUM(EXPAMT) || ' App: ' || SUM(EXPAPPRAMT)
FROM EXPITEM
group by EXPDATE;
```

when I'm trying to execute it in SQL developer, there is no problem with that query

but when I'm trying to execute in oracle application express, there is an error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: dbms_sql.describe_columns overflow, col_name_len=44. Use describe_columns2
```

anyone know what is wrong with the query in oracle application express?

Comment: Can you sum the columns with out concatenating ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use aliases for your query fields

```
SELECT EXPDATE as field1, 
       'Exp: ' || SUM(EXPAMT) || ' App: ' || SUM(EXPAPPRAMT) as field2
FROM EXPITEM
group by EXPDATE;
```

Comment: @user3051767 And the reason being that apex tries to parse the dynamic sql statement, and the identifier is over 30 chars: `col_name_len=44`. It would help if an apex version and a bit more context ("calendar" - what? where?) were stated. Apex has always indicated that the display and return columns have to have differing names and advises doing so with `d` and `r` or `display_value` and `return_value`. Usually clicking the field label for some help can help a lot.

Comment: You might want to consider not using implicit casting.  The concatenate operator is intended for character strings and clobs and your are using on numeric values.  Sometimes these implicit conversions can throw errors.